# correct settings for iis server to send Email with asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have a asp.net c# web form application for my company and i have a problem sending email from it. The server has a valid IP with port that has ping 94.183.181.25:801 
and I am trying this code to send mail

```
MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage("94.183.181.25:801", MailFrom);
Mail.Body = txtbody.Text;                                 
Mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text; 
Mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;    
Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;    
SmtpClient sp = new SmtpClient("94.183.181.25:801");                                                                                           
try    
{ 
   sp.Send(Mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{    
   lblSuccessMessage.Text = ex.ToString();
   lblSuccessMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;  
}
```

I have tried to set SMTP-Email settings in IIS with settings in code but it is not working.

Comment: what version of iis are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may check out the [Configure SMTP E-mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28WS.10%29.aspx) to configure the IIS7 settings. In your IIS manager you need to check the mail settings.

Try to do the following steps:

- Firstly go to IIS Manager
- Then go to the top level site to configure for all of the server or
  go to your specific site
- Next you need to open the Feartures View
- After that open SMTP Email
- Finally you need to set the appropriate mail details which you want to configure